# Keep caches when removing usb mass storage

Tags: linux, caching, usb

This is more a wonder than a question but recntly, someone I know who was in a hurry did this : He cut a file (Ctrl+X), then, pasted it in an usb key folder and as soon as the transfer was finished, simply removed the usb key from the computer, plugged it in the other one only to find that the USB key was empty and so was now the folder on the computer.

My question is this: Is it possible (as in "implementable"), under linux to keep the cache of a removable media when it is unplugged so that, if you mistakenly remove it, you could plug it back in and continue the transfer ?

I suppose it would be a problem at the removable media level as it is unplugged while writing and we can't be sure what is written and what is not but couldn't that be circumvented ?
Maybe another problem would be that mounting and unmounting would chage the state of things on the file system ?

Can you give me some hints ? Some possibilities ? I can't find anything on this subject on the web (and no, I am not looking for the *sync* mount option...)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible (as in "implementable"), under linux to keep the cache of a removable media when it is unplugged [...]

This is a *very bad* idea: The removeable media might be written to between unplugging and reattaching it to the system (e.g. by another PC). The cache could not accept these changes, destroying the newly written data.